# Azure Mobile App malfunctioning after migration

Tags: node.js, azure, migration, azure-mobile-services

A couple weeks back our Mobile App was migrated from the old portal to the new one and it hasn't behaved properly since.

Our main issues are:

- We cannot access any logs files, the tab for Diagnostics logs stopped working entirely on Wednesday but even before that we never got any useful data out of this. When something goes wrong with our nodejs backend we can't find any clue as to what went wrong like we could in our old portal under the logs tab.
- We are unable to access the FTP server entirely, it just won't let us login even though the credentials are correct and have been reset multiple times in attempts to get them working.
- The server is throwing errors about not having enough disk space left even though we should have 53Gb to go (we're currently using 1.05Gb out of 55Gb)
- Our deployments slots are not working at all, when we push our code to the deployment slot it just doesn't work, every request we make to the deployment slots tells us we're not allowed to do anything.

We are running a standard tier Mobile App server. The backend is in NodeJS, our CMS is in ASP.Net and our app itself is in Xamarin Forms.

The issues started after we migrated the server a couple weeks back from the manage.azure.com portal to portal.azure.com.

What can we do?

Edit:

We got through to Microsoft via the payed support plan which we're getting refunded because these are basic functionalities which don't work as advertised after the migration. I've got a call with them in about three hours to get things sorted, if I learn anything we can do ourselves I will update this post to share the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be a support request to Microsoft.

If you can, open an incident with Microsoft Support.  If you can't, post a question in the [MSDN Community Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=azuremobile&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc).  (We need to ask about particulars of your site and that isn't an appropriate topic for SO)

Comment: We've been able to reach them yesterday through the payed support program and we're getting our money back for that plus A level support instead of C, got a call with them in about 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

As the architecture of Mobile Apps is changed from Mobile Services, now the mobile apps migrate to Azure App Services.

Actually the Mobile Apps backend in Node.js is an expressjs project, and the [mobile app sdk for node](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/) is a middleware of express. So the way for diagnostics and troubleshooting has changed from before we use Mobile Service. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#Debugging for details about **Debugging and troubleshooting** for mobile services.

Additionally, we can leverage the Visual Studio Team Services editor as the section **How to: Edit code in Visual Studio Team Services** shows in the link above, we can monitor the output of the Mobile Apps backend application. E.G:
 [image]

About your FTP issue, please double check your deployment Username, when we login to FTP server on Azure, we need to input the full FTP user name which is "`app\username`":
[image: https://acom.azurecomcdn.net/80C57D/cdn/mediahandler/docarticles/dpsmedia-prod/azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/20151223054713/configure02.png]

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/#enabling-diagnostic-logs for details.

Comment: The code debugging I will have a look at later today, the FTP just flat out doesn't work on the main server, a malfunctioning staging server did allow us to enter the FTP server but the main one just refused it (with the right username and password which has been reset multiple times). I've also got a call with Microsoft in about 3 hours as we finally got through to them and we're also getting our money back for the support plan as we just shouldn't have to pay for a faulty migration.